# Python BST, change data of leaf nodes

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm trying create a function to change the data in the leaf nodes (the ones with no children nodes) in a binary search tree to "Leif". Currently I have this code for my BST:

```
def add(tree, value, name):
    if tree == None:
        return {'data':value, 'data1':name, 'left':None, 'right':None}
    elif value < tree['data']:
        tree['left'] = add(tree['left'],value,name)
        return tree
    elif value > tree['data']:
        tree['right'] = add(tree['right'],value,name)
        return tree
    else: # value == tree['data']
        return tree # ignore duplicate
```

Essentially, I want to make a function that will change the name in data1 to "Leif" when there is no children nodes. What is the best  way for me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start it yourself and post your specific problems here along with the code. Because i don't think that anybody would write all the code from scratch for you...

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem into smaller problems which can be solved with simple functions.

```
from itertools import ifilter


def is_leaf(tree):
    return tree['left'] is None and tree['right'] is None


def traverse(tree):
    if tree is not None:
        yield tree
        for side in ['left', 'right']:
            for child in traverse(tree[side]):
                yield child


def set_data1_in_leafes_to_leif(tree):
    for leaf in ifilter(is_leaf, traverse(tree)):
        leaf['data1'] = 'Leif'
```